# How to mock a nested client in test

Tags: unit-testing, go

I am building a simple function that calls an API that returns a Post using GraphQL (https://github.com/machinebox/graphql). I wrapped the logic in a service that looks like this:

```golang
type Client struct {
    gcl graphqlClient
}
type graphqlClient interface {
    Run(ctx context.Context, req *graphql.Request, resp interface{}) error
}
func (c *Client) GetPost(id string) (*Post, error) {
    req := graphql.NewRequest(`
        query($id: String!) {
          getPost(id: $id) {
            id
            title
          }
        }
    `)
    req.Var("id", id)
    var resp getPostResponse
    if err := c.gcl.Run(ctx, req, &resp); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return resp.Post, nil
}
```

Now I'd like to add [test tables](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/TableDrivenTests) for the `GetPost` function with a fail case when `id` is set to empty string which causes an error in the downstream call `c.gcl.Run`.

What I am struggling with is the way the `gcl` client can be mocked and forced to return the error (when no real API call happens).

My test so far:

```golang
package apiClient

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp"
    "github.com/machinebox/graphql"
    "testing"
)

type graphqlClientMock struct {
    graphqlClient
    HasError bool
    Response interface{}
}

func (g graphqlClientMock) Run(_ context.Context, _ *graphql.Request, response interface{}) error {
    if g.HasError {
        return errors.New("")
    }

    response = g.Response

    return nil
}

func newTestClient(hasError bool, response interface{}) *Client {
    return &Client{
        gcl: graphqlClientMock{
            HasError: hasError,
            Response: response,
        },
    }
}

func TestClient_GetPost(t *testing.T) {
    tt := []struct{
        name string
        id string
        post *Post
        hasError bool
        response getPostResponse
    }{
        {
            name: "empty id",
            id: "",
            post: nil,
            hasError: true,
        },
        {
            name: "existing post",
            id: "123",
            post: &Post{id: aws.String("123")},
            response: getPostResponse{
                Post: &Post{id: aws.String("123")},
            },
        },
    }

    for _, tc := range tt {
        t.Run(tc.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            client := newTestClient(tc.hasError, tc.response)
            post, err := client.GetPost(tc.id)

            if err != nil {
                if tc.hasError == false {
                    t.Error("unexpected error")
                }
            } else {
                if tc.hasError == true {
                    t.Error("expected error")
                }
                if cmp.Equal(post, &tc.post) == false {
                    t.Errorf("Response data do not match: %s", cmp.Diff(post, tc.post))
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I am not sure if passing the `response` to the mock like this is the right way to do it. Also, I'm struggling to set the right value to the response, since an `interface{}` type is passed and I don't know how to convert it to the `getPostResponse` and set the value to `Post` there.

Comment: Have you already tried running this against a real client? I'm asking because you're passing a non-pointer response to Run which will not be able to set anything to it... check the docs on Run to see if they don't mention that resp should be a pointer to whatever.

Comment: ... though they're not explicit about it *"**unmarshals** the response from the data field **into** the response object."* cannot be done without a pointer. Also their example at the top of the docs shows as much: `client.Run(ctx, req, &respData)` ([docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/machinebox/graphql))

Comment: @mkopriva Sorry, I forgot to specify the pointer when copying the code to the question. The code executes fine with a real client.

Comment: How can this be messed up while copying? Please extract a [mcve], because _not_ copying seems to be the problem here.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt My apologies, when I copy the code to SO I usually rename all the variables. I must have deleted the `&` by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test cases *should not* go beyond the implementation. I'm specifically referring to the empty-vs-nonempty input or any kind of input really.

Let's take a look at the code you want to test:

```
func (c *Client) GetPost(id string) (*Post, error) {
    req := graphql.NewRequest(`
        query($id: String!) {
            getPost(id: $id) {
                id
                title
            }
        }
    `)
    req.Var("id", id)

    var resp getPostResponse
    if err := c.gcl.Run(ctx, req, &resp); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return resp.Post, nil
}
```

Nothing in the implementation above is doing anything based on the `id` parameter value and therefore nothing in your tests for this piece of code should really care about what input is passed in, if it is irrelevant to the implementation it should also be irrelevant to the tests.

Your `GetPost` has basically two code branches that are taken based on a single factor, i.e. the "nilness" of the returned `err` variable. This means that as far as your implementation is concerned there are only two possible outcomes, based on what `err` value `Run` returns, and therefore there should only be two test cases, a 3rd or 4th test case would be just a variation, if not an outright copy, of the first two.

---

Your test client is also doing some unnecessary stuff, the main one being its name, i.e. what you have there is not a mock so calling it that is not helpful. Mocks usually do a lot more than just return predefined values, they ensure that methods are called, in the expected order and with the expected arguments, etc. And actually you don't need a mock here at all so it's a good thing it isn't one.

With that in mind, here's what I would suggest you do with your test client.

```
type testGraphqlClient struct {
    resp interface{} // non-pointer value of the desired response, or nil
    err  error       // the error to be returned by Run, or nil
}

func (g testGraphqlClient) Run(_ context.Context, _ *graphql.Request, resp interface{}) error {
    if g.err != nil {
        return g.err
    }

    if g.resp != nil {
        // use reflection to set the passed in response value
        // (i haven't tested this so there may be a bug or two)
        reflect.ValueOf(resp).Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(g.resp))
    }
    return nil
}
```

... and here are the necessary test cases, all two of them:

```
func TestClient_GetPost(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []struct {
        name   string
        post   *Post
        err    error
        client testGraphqlClient
    }{{
        name:   "return error from client",
        err:    errors.New("bad input"),
        client: testGraphqlClient{err: errors.New("bad input")},
    }, {
        name:   "return post from client",
        post:   &Post{id: aws.String("123")},
        client: testGraphqlClient{resp: getPostResponse{Post: &Post{id: aws.String("123")}}},
    }}

    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            client := Client{gql: tt.client}
            post, err := client.GetPost("whatever")
            if !cmp.Equal(err, tt.err) {
                t.Errorf("got error=%v want error=%v", err, tt.err)
            }
            if !cmp.Equal(post, tt.post) {
                t.Errorf("got post=%v want post=%v", post, tt.post)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

... there's a bit of repetition going on here, the need to spell out the `post` and `err` twice but that's a small price to pay when compared to a more sophisticated/complicated test setup that would populate the test client from the test case's expected output fields.

---

**Addendum:**

If you were to update `GetPost` in such a way that it checks for the empty id and returns an error before it sends a request to graphql then your initial setup would make much more sense:

```
func (c *Client) GetPost(id string) (*Post, error) {
    if id == "" {
        return nil, errors.New("empty id")
    }
    req := graphql.NewRequest(`
        query($id: String!) {
            getPost(id: $id) {
                id
                title
            }
        }
    `)
    req.Var("id", id)

    var resp getPostResponse
    if err := c.gcl.Run(ctx, req, &resp); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return resp.Post, nil
}
```

... and updating the test cases accordingly:

```
func TestClient_GetPost(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []struct {
        name   string
        id     string
        post   *Post
        err    error
        client testGraphqlClient
    }{{
        name:   "return empty id error",
        id:     "",
        err:    errors.New("empty id"),
        client: testGraphqlClient{},
    }, {
        name:   "return error from client",
        id:     "nonemptyid",
        err:    errors.New("bad input"),
        client: testGraphqlClient{err: errors.New("bad input")},
    }, {
        name:   "return post from client",
        id:     "nonemptyid",
        post:   &Post{id: aws.String("123")},
        client: testGraphqlClient{resp: getPostResponse{Post: &Post{id: aws.String("123")}}},
    }}

    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            client := Client{gql: tt.client}
            post, err := client.GetPost(tt.id)
            if !cmp.Equal(err, tt.err) {
                t.Errorf("got error=%v want error=%v", err, tt.err)
            }
            if !cmp.Equal(post, tt.post) {
                t.Errorf("got post=%v want post=%v", post, tt.post)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I added a custom comparer for the errors because it's a different error every time so I'm comparing error messages instead, is this viable approach? https://play.golang.org/p/j6e1FkWvZLV

Comment: @JanRichter keep in mind that two different `error` implementations, representing different problems in your code, could return the same `string` from `Error()` e.g. https://play.golang.com/p/yCbb2C0hp32. So in general I would not consider it to be viable but if you know the range of errors that can be returned from the unit under test and you know that it's good enough to just compare them by the strings, then sure, it can be viable.